# Displaying Video On Secondary Screen using Android Presentation Class

Tags: java, android, video, dialog, android-videoview

**I am developing an app where** one of the features is to have two buttons which when touched would display one of two locally stored videos on a secondary monitor in full screen. The monitor is connected directly with an HDMI cable as the tablet I'm using has an HDMI-out port. There is no need to control video playback with seeking or stopping. The video can simply start over (seek to 0) when the button is pressed again. If the user is playing video1 and presses the video2 button the assumption would be that video1 would immediately stop and video2 would begin.

The current implementation (of which a stub is included below) basically works as intended. When I first connect the secondary display, launch the app and press either button the associated video begins playing in the VideoView. If I click the button again or click the other button the associated video begins playing from the start.

**The bug I'm running into occurs when** I either exit the app using the back button, if I background the app using the overview button, or if I exit the app by swiping it away in the app overview. The next time I open the app and click on one of the video buttons, nothing occurs on my secondary display. It simply remains as a mirror of my Tablet's main display. If I detach and reattach my secondary display, even while the app is open, the buttons start working as intended. This leads me to believe I am not properly cleaning up either the Presentation, MediaRouter or VideoView upon app pause or stop. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If adding the main activity code would help, let me know.

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRouter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Presentation;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;


public class GuiFragment extends Fragment{
    private MediaRouter mMediaRouter;
    private VideoPresentation mPresentation;

    public GuiFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("GuiFragment", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the media router service.
        mMediaRouter = (MediaRouter) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.e("GuiFragment", "onPause");
        // Be sure to call the super class.
        super.onPause();

        // Dismiss the presentation when the activity is not visible.
        stopVideo();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("GuiFragment", "onCreateView");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connection_gui, container, false);

        // Initialize Button objects
        Button video1Button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vid1_button);
        Button video2Button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vid2_button);

        video1Button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.e("GuiFragment", "video1 button event");
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        MediaRouter.RouteInfo route = mMediaRouter.getSelectedRoute(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO);
                        if (route != null) {
                            Log.e("GuiFragment", "Obtained Video Media Route");
                            Display presentationDisplay = route.getPresentationDisplay();
                            if (presentationDisplay != null) {
                                Log.e("GuiFragment", "Obtained Presentation Display, Presenting Video");
                                //if (mPresentation == null)
                                //{
                                    Log.e("GuiFragment", "Video1: No presentation, create a new one");
                                    mPresentation = new VideoPresentation(getActivity(), presentationDisplay,
                                            Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bigbuckbunny));
                                    mPresentation.show();
                                //}
                                //else
                                //{
                                //    Log.e("GuiFragment", "Video1: Presentation exists, update URI");
                                //    mPresentation.stopVideoView();
                                //    mPresentation.updateVideo(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bigbuckbunny));
                                //}
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Display", duration);
                                toast.show();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No MediaRouter", duration);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                /* This causes onClick not to be called. You would need it for accessibility options
                   but we don't really care about that in this app */
                return true;
            }
        });

        video2Button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.e("GuiFragment", "video2 button event");
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        MediaRouter.RouteInfo route = mMediaRouter.getSelectedRoute(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO);
                        if (route != null) {
                            Log.e("GuiFragment", "Obtained Video Media Route");
                            Display presentationDisplay = route.getPresentationDisplay();
                            if (presentationDisplay != null) {
                                Log.e("GuiFragment", "Obtained Presentation Display, Presenting Video");
                                //if (mPresentation == null)
                                //{
                                    Log.e("GuiFragment", "Video2: No presentation, create a new one");
                                    mPresentation = new VideoPresentation(getActivity(), presentationDisplay,
                                            Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bigbuckbunny));
                                    mPresentation.show();
                                //}
                                //else
                                //{
                                //    Log.e("GuiFragment", "Video2: Presentation exists, update URI");
                                //    mPresentation.stopVideoView();
                                //    mPresentation.updateVideo(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bigbuckbunny));
                                //}
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Display", duration);
                                toast.show();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No MediaRouter", duration);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                /* This causes onClick not to be called. You would need it for accessibility options
                   but we don't really care about that in this app */
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    private void stopVideo() {
        Log.e("GuiFragment", "stopVideo()");
        if (mPresentation != null) {
            Log.e("GuiFragment", "Stopping video1 playback");
            mPresentation.stopVideoView();
            mPresentation.dismiss();
            mPresentation = null;
        }
    }



    private final static class VideoPresentation extends Presentation {

        VideoView mVideoView;
        Context mContext;
        Uri mVideo;

        public VideoPresentation(Context context, Display display, Uri video) {
            super(context, display);
            mContext = context;
            mVideo = video;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.e("VideoPresentation", "onCreate");
            // Be sure to call the super class.
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Get the resources for the context of the presentation.
            // Notice that we are getting the resources from the context of the presentation.
            Resources r = getContext().getResources();

            // Inflate the layout.
            setContentView(R.layout.presentation_with_media_router_activity);

            mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(mVideo);

            mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mVideoView.start();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            Log.e("VideoPresentation", "onStart");
            // Be sure to call the super class.
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            Log.e("VideoPresentation", "onStop");
            // Be sure to call the super class.
            super.onStop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
            Log.e("VideoPresentation", "onDetachedFromWindow");
            // Be sure to call the super class.
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        }

        public void stopVideoView() {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        }

        public void updateVideo(Uri video) {
            mVideo = video;
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(mVideo);
        }

        public VideoView getVideoView() {
            return mVideoView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem?